GetDataSourceItem<T>() does not exist in current context
I am upgrading Glass.Mapper from V4 to V5. In the documentation they have mention that some of the features are removed. IContentSliderTeaser contentSliderTeaser = GetDataSourceItem<IContentSliderTeaser>(); This line is throwing error for me.
Is there an alternate to maintain the same functionality without using this deprecated code.

I have reffered this documentation Glass.Mapper|Documentation|Upgrade-ToV5.html

You will need to replace GlassController with SitecoreController and use mvc context property injected in the constructor to read the datasource as below.
public class ArticleController : SitecoreController //or Controller
{
   private readonly IMvcContext _mvcContext;
   public ArticleController(IMvcContext mvcContext)
   {
       _mvcContext = mvcContext;
   }
   public void FetchArticleData(){
     var datasourceItem = _mvcContext.GetDataSourceItem<IArticle>();
   }
}

Note: In order to inject mvc context through dependency injection, make sure dependency for ISitecoreService and IMvcContext has been registered as below in the service collection.
using Glass.Mapper.Sc;
using Glass.Mapper.Sc.Web.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Sitecore;
using Sitecore.DependencyInjection;

namespace SitecoreCustomExtensions.DependencyInjection
{
  public class GlassMapperServiceConfigurator : IServicesConfigurator
  {
    public void Configure(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
    {
      serviceCollection.AddScoped<ISitecoreService>(sp => new SitecoreService(Context.Database));
      serviceCollection.AddScoped<IMvcContext>(sp => new MvcContext(sp.GetService<ISitecoreService>()));
    }
  }
}

This service configuration should then be registered as below through Sitecore patch file.
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
   <services>
      <configurator type="SitecoreCustomExtensions.DependencyInjection.GlassMapperServiceConfigurator,SitecoreCustomExtensions" />
    </services>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>

Update:
You can also get mvcContext inside your application through below code.
using Glass.Mapper.Sc;
using Glass.Mapper.Sc.Web.Mvc;

var mvcContext = new MvcContext(new SitecoreService(Sitecore.Context.Database));
var datasourceItem = mvcContext.GetDataSourceItem<IArticle>();

Update 16/10/2024:
Datasource model should be set as below in order to read the properties for the same.
using Glass.Mapper.Sc.Configuration;
using Glass.Mapper.Sc.Configuration.Attributes;

[SitecoreType(TemplateId = "{57BCF1CE-35CB-4752-B23B-2D4522AF6292}")]
public class IArticle 
{
   // Mandatory for Glassmapper DO NOT delete
   [SitecoreInfo(SitecoreInfoType.Name)]
   string Name { get; set; }
   // Mandatory for Glassmapper DO NOT delete
   [SitecoreInfo(SitecoreInfoType.TemplateName)]
   string Template { get; set; }
   // Mandatory for Glassmapper DO NOT delete
   [SitecoreId]
   Guid Id { get; set; }
   [SitecoreField(FieldId = "{63D62924-8CA7-4A59-ADD0-F1C0ADE0E1C3}")]
   public virtual string Heading { get; set; }
}

In order to read the properties with lazy loading disabled, you can execute following code.
using Glass.Mapper;
using Glass.Mapper.Sc;

var options = new GetKnownOptions { Lazy = LazyLoading.Disabled };
var datasourceItem = this.MvcContext.GetDataSourceItem<IArticle>(options);

Hope this helps!!! Let me know in case you have any queries.

Thanks for your help. I have one query. I have public class GlassMapperServiceConfigurator : IServicesConfigurator already written in my project.
Can I add serviceCollection.AddScoped<ISitecoreService>(sp => new SitecoreService(Context.Database));       serviceCollection.AddScoped<IMvcContext>(sp => new MvcContext(sp.GetService<ISitecoreService>())); in the existing one?

yes @MohitPatil you can add them in the existing one..

Thank you  @ckhanna for your swift response. Just one thing I want to mention, I am updating Context inthis line serviceCollection.AddScoped<ISitecoreService>(sp => new SitecoreService(Context.Database)); with Sitecore.Context. Just writing Context is throwing an error. Let me know if this can work or not. Thank you.

@MohitPatil for this you may need to add Sitecore Reference in your class as i have mentioned in my answer bellow.

@MohitPatil I have added using in the above class..You can add those using inside your class and let me know in case you face any issues.

ya we need to add Sitecore.Context, therefore i have added using Sitecore reference on the above class..

@MohitPatil Were you able to add those reference in the solution and test the changes..Let me know in case any help is needed..

@ckhanna I did all the above mentioned changes. After deploying them to local web server, iam trying to load th site. I got 500 error. When I started debugging the code, I noticed that _mvcContext is null. resulting in Object reference not set to an instance of an object. error.

@MohitPatil can you check dependency for mvccontext is registered on the dependency injection page..

@MohitPatil you can check the dependency for mvcContext inside the sitecore/admin/ShowServicesConfig.aspx page.

Also I updated the answer above where in you get the mvccontext by constructing this object. Let me know in case you face any issues

@ckhanna Thasnks for the update. I checked, it is registered on the dependency injection. Also tried the updated solution. When I look in deeper I noticed that the result of GetDataSourceItem<T>() is having null/empty values. Looks like GlassMapper is creating proxy model.
I tried adding lazy loading disabler. It is throwing depth check failed error.

@MohitPatil Can you check the the glass model is initialized as above. If possible can we connect over call on Sitecore Slack to check the configurations.

Also @MohitPatil you need to set the lazy loading as above while retrieving item and make sure the model attributes are not cacheable.

@MohitPatil is this Id available on Sitecore Slack?

@MohitPatil you can join this Sitecore chat group. https://sitecore.chat. Let me know in case you face any issues.

@ckhanna thank you for your help. Datasource model implementetion was the issue. I have implemented the model in the it is mentioned in the answer above. Issue is resolved now.

Glad to hear that @MohitPatil!!!

You need to replace GlassController with SitecoreController. Use the mvc context property, which is injected in the constructor, to access the datasource as shown in the following example.
public class AdvertisingController : SitecoreController 
{
   private readonly IMvcContext _mvcContext;
   public AdvertisingController (IMvcContext mvcContext)
   {
       _mvcContext = mvcContext;
   }

    public Partner GetPartner(Rendering rendering)
    {
         try
          {
                var ModelData = _mvcContext.GetDataSourceItem<Partner>();
                return ModelData;
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
                throw ex;
          }
      }
}

If you already have a GlassMapperServiceConfigurator class, modify it as described below. If not, create a new GlassMapperServiceConfigurator class in your project's root directory. This class will be used to register ISitecoreService and IMvcContext .
using Glass.Mapper.Sc;
using Glass.Mapper.Sc.Web;
using Glass.Mapper.Sc.Web.Mvc;
using Glass.Mapper.Sc.Web.WebForms;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Sitecore;
using Sitecore.Data;
using Sitecore.DependencyInjection;

namespace Project.Website
{
    public class GlassMapperServiceConfigurator : IServicesConfigurator
    {
        public void Configure(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
        {
            serviceCollection.AddTransient<ISitecoreService>(sp => new SitecoreService(Context.Database));
            serviceCollection.AddTransient<IMvcContext>(sp => new MvcContext(sp.GetService<ISitecoreService>()));
         }
    }
}


After that you need to add a patch file to register this service configuration in a Sitecore patch file using the following method.
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
    <sitecore>
        <services>
        <configurator type="Project.Website.GlassMapperServiceConfigurator,  Project.Website" />
        </services>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>

Hope this helps!!!
